# return a dictionary of Tuples as a return type of a function in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, group-by, tuples

I have a dictionary as follow:

```
  var returnedresult = (from v in vaults.Where(v => v.IntegrationTypeInternal == (int)integrationType)
                                  join c in DB.Cobrands on v.Cobrand.ID equals c.ID
                                  join p in DB.TaxPartners on c.ID equals p.Cobrand.ID
                                  join pb in DB.TaxPartnerBranches on p.ID equals pb.Partner.ID
                                  join pa in DB.TaxPartnerAgents on pb.ID equals pa.Branch.ID
                                  join pac in DB.Accounts on pa.Account.ID equals pac.ID
                                  where v.Account == null || v.Account.ID == pac.ID
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      v.Account,
                                      v.Cobrand,
                                      v.CredentialsXml,
                                      pac
                                  }).ToList();


var myDictionary2 = returnedresult.GroupBy(x => new { x.Account, x.Cobrand, x.CredentialsXml },
            (key, group) => new
            {
                key1 = key.Account,
                key2 = key.Cobrand,
                key3 = key.CredentialsXml,
                result = group.Select(g => g.pac).ToList()
            });
```

Is it possible to use a **Tuple** instead of this dictionary Key? I want to return this dictionary in a function , and I dont know how can I return it without creating a new type as object for **dictionary Key**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return anything with Linq.

```
var myDictionary2 = returnedresult.GroupBy(x => new { x.Account, x.Cobrand, x.CredentialsXml },
        (key, group) => Tuple.Create(key.Account, key.Cobrand, key.CredentialsXml, group.Select(g => g.pac).ToList());
```